# Ruby: Help improving hashing algorithm

Tags: ruby, performance, hash, blockchain

I am still relatively new to ruby as a language, but I know there are a lot of convenience methods built into the language. I am trying to generate a "hash" to check against in a low level block-chain verifier and I am wondering if there are any "convenience methods" that I could you to try to make this hashing algorithm more efficient. I think I can make this more efficient by utilizing ruby's max integer size, but I'm not sure.

Below is the current code which takes in a string to hash, unpacks it into an array of UTF-8 values, does computationally intensive math to each one of those values, adds up all of those values after the math is done to them, takes that value modulo 65,536, and then returns the hex representation of that value.

```
def generate_hash(string)
  unpacked_string = string.unpack('U*')
  sum = 0
  unpacked_string.each do |x|
    sum += (x**2000) * ((x + 2)**21) - ((x + 5)**3)
  end
  new_val = sum % 65_536 # Gives a number from 0 to 65,535
  new_val.to_s(16)
end
```

On very large block-chains there is a very large performance hit which I am trying to get around. Any help would be great!

Comment: Why not use a built-in hashing method from the [standard library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/SHA2.html)? These can benefit from optimizations written in C where your code can't.

Comment: Just wondering why you feel anything you write in Ruby is going to somehow be more efficient than Ruby's built-in hashing it performs on strings in C? Something wrong with `"Hello, world!".hash`?

Comment: What kind of hash do you need? Ruby's built in hash is for making hash tables of objects, it isn't necessarily cryptographically secure.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, it is extremely unlikely that you are going to create anything that is more efficient than simply using `String#hash`. This is a case of you trying to build a better mousetrap.

Honestly, your hashing algorithm is very inefficient. The entire point of a hash is to be a fast, low-overhead way of quickly getting a "unique" (as unique as possible) integer to represent any object to avoid comparing by values.

Using that as a premise, if you start doing any type of intense computation in a hash algorithm, it is already counter-productive. Once you start implementing `modulo` and `pow` functions, it is inefficient.

Usually best practice involves taking a value(s) of the object that can be represented as integers, and performing bit operations on them, typically with prime numbers to help reduce hash collisions.

```
def hash
  h = value1 ^ 393
  h += value2 ^ 17
  h
end
```

In your example, you are for some reason forcing the hash to the max value of a 16-bit unsigned integer, when typically 32-bits is used, although if you are comparing on the Ruby-side, this would be 31-bits due to how Ruby masks Fixnum values. Fixnum was deprecated on the Ruby side as it should have been, but internally the same threshold exists between what how a `Bignum` and `Fixnum` are handled. The `Integer` class simply provides one interface on the Ruby side, as those two really should never have been exposed outside of the C code.

In your specific example using strings, I would simply symbolize them. This guarantees a quick and efficient way that determines if two strings are equal without hardly any overhead, and comparing 2 symbols is the exact same as comparing 2 integers. There is a caveat to this method if you are comparing a vast number of strings. Once a symbol is created, it is alive for the life of the program. Any additional strings that equal to it will return the same symbol, but you cannot remove the memory of the symbol (just a few bytes) for as long as the program runs. Not good if using this method to compare thousands and thousands of unique strings.

Comment: Symbolizing arbitrary strings is not really a good plan as it clutters up the symbol table.

Comment: As I was pointing out in an edit when you were typing that, lol :)

Comment: I understand that I am trying to "reinvent the wheel" in a way instead of just using the built in hash function. The reason I am using this unwieldy function is because the block-chain file is already generated using those rules so I have to verify the hash of the block in the .txt file with the one I generate from this function. If I were generating the block-chain, I would use the built in method.

Comment: If you need to compare to an existing hash value generated by something else, then you have to implement it exactly the same. Efficiency is irrelevant if you are forced to an existing standard. You have to use it, no matter what it is. Could implement as C extension for a little boost, but not much can be done about that.